# Query result doesn't give the list of items, but just an empty array [ ] in aws-amplify

Tags: react-native, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I try to make a query to see the list of users. My custom lambda function (which I attached as policy) is as follows:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new aws.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  if (!event.request.userAttributes.sub) {
    console.log("Error: No user was written to DynamoDB")
    context.done(null, event);
    return;
  }

  // Save the user to DynamoDB
  const date = new Date();

  const params = {
    Item: {
      'id': { S: event.request.userAttributes.sub },
      '__typename': { S: 'User' },
      'username': { S: event.userName },
      'email': { S: event.request.userAttributes.email },
      'createdAt': { S: date.toISOString() },
      'updatedAt': { S: date.toISOString() },
    },
    TableName: process.env.USERTABLE,
  }

  try {
    await ddb.putItem(params).promise();
    console.log("Success");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error", e);
  }

  context.done(null, event);
}
```

And the schema model is as follows:

```
type User @model 
@auth(rules: [
  { allow: public, operations: [read]}
  { allow: owner }
])
{ 
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  email: String!
}
```

Although there is one user in the dynamoDb, when I make a query by:

```
query listUsers {
  listUsers {
    items {
      email
      id
      username
    }
  }
}
```

the result is as follows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "listUsers": {
      "items": []
    }
  }
}
```

As can be seen, the array of "items" is empty, the items are not shown, when I look at the console dynamoDb table, I see user items with id, username and email values. But it should give the results, where do I make mistake? Meanwhile I am new on aws-amplify.

Comment: Have you tried creating a user via AppSync Console to see the difference between your lambda and the graphql mutation?

Comment: Do you mean creating a new user in the console for testing? I didn't understand what you mean by mutations?

Comment: yes, in AppSync console, like this `mutation { createUser { ... } }`

Comment: @LuckyTuvshee I am sorry for late reply since I have been learning how to do. Now yes I tried to createUser via mutation in Appsync, and the users are succesfully added into the table, and when I query from Appsync, it lists items correctly (without empty arrays). Even if I tried with an api without a lambda function, no change in the query items, still resulting in an empty array [] if I add user from the react native application